# Change data in waterfall chart in powerpoint using openXml

Tags: c#, openxml

I have trouble with update data in waterfall chart.
If i create any chart, for example Stacked Column then i can change data in chart, because i can take ChartParts 
[image]

BUT, when i try to get data in Waterfall Chart then I get null in ChartParts
[image]

Stacked Column and Waterfall charts have a different structures.
[image]

[image]

Maybe someone has an answer on how to change data in waterfall chart in pptx file?